# VPN client application

Tags: vpn

Why would I pay to use the Sonicwall Global Client VPN application when I can use the built in Windows VPN client for free?

We are connecting to Sonicwall NSA 3500 firewalls if it makes a difference.

Comment: How would we know why you might choose to pay? Maybe you should reword this into a proper question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The windows client only supports L2TP I believe and that is generally [viewed as insecure](http://arstechnica.com/phpbb/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=48371).

One would assume the vendor client (Sonicwall Global Client) integrates more simply with your sonicwall device and perhaps offers better management functionality.  However I have no experience with this myself.

I have administered older Sonicwall devices and found them to be miserable.  Perhaps newer ones are better, I don't know.  I do know that in your position I would really look at setting up a separate [OpenVPN](http://www.openvpn.net/) vpn server and bypassing the Sonicwall devices entirely.  I've set that up [in a small office environment](http://www.hollenback.net/index.php/OpenVpnSetup) and it seems to work fine.

I'm not particularly recommending you make major changes to your setup, just pointing out alternatives.  In general I dislike using vendor-specific network boxes but that's just me.

Comment: Vista SP1/7 and Server 2k8 also support SSTP.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the only reason to use a system-specific client is if the generic client doesn't work, or if there is additional functionality added by the custom client (For example, I use the Cisco client to connect to our VPN on Windows, because the Windows client is annoying to configure, isn't pure IPSec, and isn't as easy to use, but I use the built in Mac client when connecting from a Mac.)

The security level is effectively the same for both. There is talk of vulnerabilities in the windows implementation, but it hasn't been *broken*. For SonicWall, I'd probably just use the built in client, if I could get it to work.